# Local variable became nil in an ensure clause

Tags: ruby

I've stumbled across a strange behaviour I can't explain. Executing the method

```
def with_baton
  until (baton = Baton.obtain)
    sleep(2)
  end

  result = yield
ensure
  baton.release
  result
end
```

which makes sure the block we pass to it doesn't execute in parallel by multiple workers, I sometimes receive the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `release' for nil:NilClass
lib/*hidden*/common.rb:172 in ensure in with_baton
lib/*hidden*/common.rb:173 in with_baton
lib/*hidden*/common.rb:7 in get
```

If the execution went past `until` it means `baton` is set. How could it happen that its `nil` in `ensure`? By the way, the block executes for about five seconds, and I use Ruby MRI 1.9.3-p547.

Comment: What does Baton.obtain can return? The issue is that this is returning nil in some cases, and nil is a valid assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `Baton.obtain` may raise an error, and in that case baton will be `nil`

call `baton.release if baton`